# Passing an image to another activity

Tags: android

I have an image stored on the hard drive and want to move to another activity.

In the main activity, the path that I put is as follows:

```
String address = "/ Dir_Imagen / nombre.png";
```

On the secondary activity, once I pick up the dir, put:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeFile (address);
```

The problem is that the variable icon, returns me null.

Someone knows what is wrong?

Comment: Your address has spaces in it, try removing them.

Comment: if you get the bitmap in the first activity, does it return null then (and remove the spaces as fredley said)?

Comment: @Juanfren have you seen this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544660/passing-image-to-another-activity), the same issue is discussed here.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually pass the bitmap object from one activity to the other as it's implementing parcelable:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("icon", icon);
```

Then from the second activity, get the bitmap back with:

```
Bitmap icon = (Bitmap) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("icon");
```